# How can I return the date on which a criteria was fulfilled from a list in R?

Tags: r, arrays, list, date

I want to locate the first and last date where the daily temperature is less than 0 degrees, for every year of data in a list (30 years long) and return the Julian day (Day Of Year) on which the event occurred for each cell in the grid.

Here is my example dataset:
I have 30 years of daily minimumum temperature data in a list:

```
#First create the example dataset of dimensions: Days,Lat,Lon

tmin=array(-2:35, c(10958,11,10))

#create the list

Variable <- list(varName="tmin")
Data = tmin
xyCoords <- list(x = seq(-4.37,1.37,length.out=10), y = seq(45.37,52.37,length.out=11))
Dates <- list(start = seq(as.Date("1976-01-01"), as.Date("2005-12-31"), by="days"), end=seq(as.Date("1976-01-01"), as.Date("2005-12-31"), by="days"))
All <- list(Variable = Variable,Data=Data, xyCoords=xyCoords,Dates=Dates)
#Make sure the dates are characters (as in the original dataset I'm, working with)
All$Dates$start=as.character(All$Dates$start)
All$Dates$end=as.character(All$Dates$end)
```

I want subset the data by year (so for example, year 1's data would be 1:365x11x10) to assess if each cell in the 11X10 grid for each day of that year is less than zero. The first instance of this occurring is the 'date of first frost' and I want to save down the date of this occurrence. Ultimately, I would end up with data of size 30x11x10 for the first date of occurrence, the first year of which would look something like this (an 11 x 10 matrix of DOY when the temperature dropped below zero for the first time):

[image]

I also want to create another 30x11x10 output of dates for the LAST occurrence of the temperature falling below zero.

First off, I created my Julian days/DOY:

```
#Convert the dates into julian days
require(lubridate)
tmp<-as.Date(All$Dates$start)
doy  <-  yday(tmp)
```

And extract the years:

```
yr  <-  year(tmp)
unique.yrs<-unique(yr)
```

My thinking after this is that I loop through the dates matching all instances of `unique.yrs[i]`.

```
for (i in 1:length(yr)){
  #Find the indices for the data by identifying the year
yridx<-which(yr ==unique.yrs[i], arr.ind = TRUE)
  #Get the year of data using the year indices
yr.data<-All$Data[yridx,,]
#Identify where temperatures<0 occurred
frost<-which(yr.data <0, arr.ind = TRUE)
}
```

At this point, I am returned the 3d indices for every occurence below zero:
[image]

I'm not sure where to go from here. I think if I can get the all the frost occurrences for each cell in the grid per year, then maybe I could use `head` to get the first instance and `tail` to get the last? So maybe I should be subsetting again in a loop?

I realise that I am not providing a full set of code here, but  am relatively new to R and I need to know if I am going about this all the wrong way. Is my proposed route forward too convoluted? Is there a better way?

##########################################################################################################################################################
#This is what I came up with...it's not elegant, but it works I think:

```
firstoccur=array(numeric(),c(30,11,10))
lastoccur=array(numeric(),c(30,11,10))
yrcntr<-0
for (j in unique.yrs) {
  indcntr<-0
  yrcntr<-yrcntr+1
  ind=which(yr==j)

  for (i in ind) {
    indcntr<-indcntr+1
    for (ii in 1:11){
      for (jj in 1:10){
        if (Data[i,ii,jj]<0 && is.na(firstoccur[yrcntr,ii,jj])){
          firstoccur[yrcntr,ii,jj]<-doy[ind[indcntr]]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This procedure creates two lists, `my_list_first` and `my_list_last`. My_list_first is a list of length 30 with identifiers each of the years from 1976 to 2005. The first entry of each entry is the exact date that the temperature dropped below 0 for the first time, and the second entry is the 11x10 grid associated with that day. For example,

```
 my_list_first[[1]][[1]]
 "1976-01-01"
 my_list_first[[30]][[1]]
 "2005-01-01"
 my_list_last[["2000"]][[2]]
      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
 [1,]    9   11   13   15   17   19   21   23   25    27
 [2,]   23   25   27   29   31   33   35   -1    1     3
 [3,]   -1    1    3    5    7    9   11   13   15    17
 [4,]   13   15   17   19   21   23   25   27   29    31
 [5,]   27   29   31   33   35   -1    1    3    5     7
 [6,]    3    5    7    9   11   13   15   17   19    21
 [7,]   17   19   21   23   25   27   29   31   33    35
 [8,]   31   33   35   -1    1    3    5    7    9    11
 [9,]    7    9   11   13   15   17   19   21   23    25
 [10,]   21   23   25   27   29   31   33   35   -1     1
 [11,]   35   -1    1    3    5    7    9   11   13    15
```

The code operates by going forward within each year starting from the first day to find the date of first occurrence of below zero temperature, and then going backward from the last day of each year to find the last day of below zero temperature. It stores this information in lists called my_list_first and my_list_last. Each key is the year, and each entry has two components, the exact date and the latitude/longitude grid of temperatures.

```
my_list_first=list()
my_list_last=list()
for (j in unique.yrs) {
  ind=which(yr==j)
  firstoccur=numeric()
  lastoccur=numeric()
  for (i in ind) {
    if (any(tmin[i,,]<0)) {
      firstoccur=i
      break
    }
  }
  for (i in rev(ind)) {
    if (any(tmin[i,,]<0)) {
      lastoccur=i
      break
    }
  }
  my_list_first[[toString(j)]]=list(All$Dates$start[firstoccur], tmin[firstoccur,,])
  my_list_last[[toString(j)]]=list(All$Dates$start[lastoccur], tmin[lastoccur,,])
}
```

Comment: I like where you're going with this, but it doesn't give me what I need I'm afraid. I need the date of occurrence for every cell in the 11x10 matrix. For example, in `my_list_last` above, I need a date (in DOY) in every i,j index: `my_list_last[["2000"]][[2]][i,j]` instead of latitude?

Comment: Not sure I understand, what kind of dates go in the 11x10 grid? Isn’t there just one date per year that the temperature drops below 0 for the first & last time?

Comment: Yes, exactly. But that date can be different for each i,j cell in the 11x10 grid (because each cell is a different location. I actually figured it out with a loop (added to question above). Thanks for your help. You set me in the right direction.

Comment: By the way, in case you wanted an alternative, this gets the same result. I checked using the `identical` function with your result and the one from this. `year=1
for (j in unique.yrs) {
  ind=which(yr==j)
  for (i in 1:11) {
    for (k in 1:10) {
      firstoccur[year,i,k]=which(tmin[ind,i,k]<0)[1]
      lastoccur[year,i,k]=which(tmin[rev(ind),i,k]<0)[1]
    }
  }
  year=year+1
}`

Comment: Half way there! You're solution is a lot tidier for `firstoccur`, but for `lastoccur` you can't use the `ind` directly as an index (because it is reversed). This is solved below by subtracting the length of ind and adding 1 to get the index. `lastoccur=array(numeric(),c(30,11,10))
year=1 
for (j in unique.yrs) {   
  ind=which(yr==j)   
  for (i in 1:11) {     
    for (k in 1:10) {       
      lastoccur[year,i,k]=(length(ind)+ 1)  - which(tmin[rev(ind),i,k]<0)[1]    
    }   
  }   
  year=year+1 }` Thanks for your help! Much appreciated.